# Why is Firefox font rendering so bold?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, firefox, fonts

When I compare https://www.example.com on Chrome and Firefox, I see bolder results on Firefox than on Chrome.

Why is this? And how can I fix it?

(Top screenshot is Chrome, bottom is Firefox.)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Looking at your image, I'm not seeing a difference in boldness.  But I'm looking at the image in Firefox.  Perhaps Firefox renders the two halves the same.

Comment: @fixer1234: What? That's impossible. Try overlaying them on top of each other in Paint. The difference is there; it's probably just that it's too subtle for you to notice.

Comment: Maybe the antialiasing is different in both browser

Comment: There is nothing to fix. The browsers are simply using different methods to render text, result in *slight* differences in metrics calculations and ClearType.

Comment: @DanielB: OK, replace "fix Firefox" with "make Firefox render like Chrome".

Comment: Chrome switched at some point in the last year to use Direct3D for rendering instead of GDI. I'm not sure what Firefox's rendering stack is, but I would guess the difference is there.

Comment: @NextInLine: I believe they both use Direct2D now?

Answer (score 5):

The spacing is slightly different, but I think it's an optical illusion based on the anti-aliasing and edge colors.  Here are a few snippets zoomed to 800%:

Chrome then Firefox bold letters:

[image]
[image]

Chrome normal text:
[image]

Firefox normal text:
[image]

The dark appearance of the letter is created by an "average" or collective darkness of several adjacent pixels.  In some cases, one browser will render the vertical bar of a normal letter with two dark colored pixels and the other will use a center very dark pixel surrounded by pixels of two light colors, or one will use two medium-dark colors side-by-side and the other will use a very dark color next to a light color.  Good examples: `t` (1st character of first line), and `pl` (second and third characters of the second line.

The darker anti-aliasing colors on the left side of the `e` make the Chrome rendering look wider than the Firefox version.  The vertical bar of the `d` looks bolder in Firefox while the vertical bar of the `b` looks bolder in Chrome.

To get more specific, compare the lowercase `m`, first letter of the second row of normal text.  For that character Firefox appears bolder when you look at the vertical lines.  Why?

Both browsers render the verticals as three columns of pixels, so the lines are actually the same width.  However, the component colors make the Firefox verticals appear wider.  Very light colors affect the apparent width less than dark colors.  Medium to dark colors (lightness value up to not much over 50%) have the greatest effect.  I sampled the color of each vertical bar and converted it to the lightness value using the HSL color space:

[image]

The first legs both have a very dark center bar with a borderline dark bar next to it.  The Firefox bars are a little darker.

For the middle leg, Chrome has only one dark bar and it's very dark (black).  Firefox has one dark bar and one medium dark bar, both "much" lighter than Chrome's black bar.  But they are both dark enough to be perceived as dark, so the Firefox leg appears wider.

For the right leg, Chrome has one dark bar and Firefox has two medium dark bars.  They are each substantially lighter than Chrome's dark bar, but dark enough to be perceived as dark, so again, that leg looks wider in Firefox.

Since these are dark letters on a white background, it is easier to think of it in terms of darkness than lightness, so the table below shows the complement values (even light colors contribute some darkness when viewed at normal size):

[image]

When looking at the characters at normal size, the total amount of "dark" in the character outline, and to some extent, the apparent width of the line, is more or less what gives the illusion of boldness.  The chart above consolidates the darkness values for all of the legs of the letter `m`.  The Firefox `m` is 15% darker than the Chrome `m`.  As described previously, the apparent line thickness is wider in Firefox, but that is not as perceptible at normal size and viewing speeds.

So Firefox's `m` appears bolder than Chrome's.  But notice that this varies from character to character.  First letter `t`, third letter, `b`, the `f` in "for", then `p` and the `t` before the `h` on the second line are among the characters that look bolder in Chrome for the same reason.

In some letters, one of the verticals looks bolder in one browser, and another vertical of the same letter looks bolder in the other browser.  For example, the `h` and `u` in "without" on the second line.

Comment: Optical illusion?! Give me a break. Just look at vertical line on the `h` in `without`!!

Comment: The width of the vertical is the same in both.  In Firefox, you have a very light color followed by two relatively dark colors.  In Chrome, you have a very dark center bar surrounded by two relatively light bars.  Look at the t before the h.  That's the reverse situation.

Comment: Great answer. Also, @Mehrdad, I'd say that _both_ don't look quite optimal on your computer; in your screenshots both examples are not quite sharp, on my screen. Like the lowercase "a" and "s" are not rendered nicely at all. If you see that too: not my cup of tea, but are you sure the correct anti-aliasing is set up for your screen? (If it looks okay for you then maybe my Macbook does not render the screenshot nicely, due to different pixel setup or anti-aliasing? Again, not my cup of tea.)

Comment: @Arjan: I don't see any suboptimality on my screen, but different OSes also render differently so you might be used to seeing different rendering... hard to say if you're seeing the same thing I'm seeing, because we need to have the same display settings (DPI and all) and given that you're on a Macbook I have no idea if your pixels map to mine 1:1. Try clicking the screenshot (don't view it embedded on this page) and then running `document.body.style.zoom = 1 / window.devicePixelRatio` in the browser console? That might work (or not).

Comment: so, how can I fix that and make fonts appear less-bold in ff?

Comment: @t3chb0t, without images of comparative examples, nobody can know what you're seeing.

Answer (score -1):

Closely examining those screenshots at high magnification, it appears that the upper (Chrome) glyphs are actually fractionally wider and bolder than the lower (Firefox) ones.

Both are using subpixel antialiasing with the appropriate RGB order for most modern displays at native resolution, though the details of kerning and hinting differ.  Notice at the end of the first line, the pair "Yo" are further apart in Chrome (indicative of poor kerning) and the entire line takes up slightly more space.

Confusion may result if you're running your monitor upside-down or in portrait orientation, or at a non-native resolution, or if it is a CRT.  Any of those things violates the assumptions of subpixel antialiasing, and you should configure your OS accordingly.